# Can Visual Studio auto-generate properties?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, getter-setter, auto-generate

Like in Eclipse for Java, where it can auto-generate getters and setters for class variables, can Visual Studio 2010 do this as well?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I usually type `prop` in the code editor and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice. Another possibility is to right click on the private field and `Refactor -> Encapsulate Field ...` or <kbd>Ctrl+R,E</kbd> but the first method is more convenient for me.

Comment: wow that is cool i never knew that. it doesn't generate everything completely, but its a lot better template than i was working with.

Comment: Beat me to it. I don't have VS installed on this machine to double check ;)

Comment: But still, is there anything to just generate all public properties for each variable in the class similar to eclipse? or is this the only way...

Comment: @Scott, I am not aware of any.

Answer (score 2):

just write propfull + TAB to auto-generate getter & setters the way Eclipse would.

Answer (score 2):

Press 'Alt + Insert', then choose 'Properties'. Though I tried it in VS 2012, not sure about 2010 but still worth a try.

There all of your class variables are visible. Select the variables that you want to create properties of. This is similar to what you have referred to in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

you aso have to option to download an addin who does that
ie : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/PropertiesGenerator.aspx